# Any way to know if my webcam is WIA supported?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, webcam, wia

I have a webcam IMX175 (Sony) which integrated into a Lenovo tablet.
How do I know if it is WIA supported (as a camera)? I tried some search code but it didn't find any devices.

Also I'll appreciate if someone can recommend me about a tool to search WIA cameras.